# Upgrade ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 black screen

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, ubuntu-14.04

Today I'ce tried to update my Ubuntu 14.04 to the latest 15.04.

The installation process works fine  until the end when it restarts... The graphical interface freezes on "Starting Light Display Manager.. and deal with any system changes.signatures...ut down....

And when I start on "upstart"
I have only a black screen...

Nethertheless, however how I start the computer, I do have an access to the 6 console interface tty on which I am able to login.

It looks like the linux version is 3.16.0-43-generic.

Thanks for any help, I am really desperate ..

Ciao !

Comment: Whats your graphic card ? Have you tried update / upgrade via ttl to see new packages fixes the issue ?

Comment: My graphic card is a Radeon.

Comment: I just dont get your ttl thing :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be happening after an update of the kernel to 3.19.0-22.
Upgrading the kernal to 4.12 might solved the issues.

Try using this,
http://www.yourownlinux.com/2015/07/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-1-2-in-linux.html

I will soon write the steps here only, till then please open the link and follow the steps.

Have a look at my blog only if your problem gets resolved
[www.techinnovators.in](http://techinnovators.in)

Comment: Finally I didn't manage to cure the problem. When I try to manually upgrade the kernel, it didn't reach the first wget...

Fortunately for me I was in dual-boot with Windows 8 so I was able to format the Ubuntu's partition and reinstall it. Ok that's a bit radical, but I didn't find any working solution...

Comment: You reinstalled ubuntu 15.04? And is it working now without the issue?

Comment: Exactly yeah ! I am really surprise ^^

Comment: i think it was issue with the kernel version only. Anyway you got it right Enjoy!!! If you get some time have a look at my website i mentioned above. you may find some useful things there in programming section and suggest me some changes.